# Unable to deploy Twitter Loader app to bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

Following the youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANakSSGM4zU

When clicked Deploy to Bluemix for Twitter-Loader service. It only completes first step i.e. Create project. It does not complete rest of the steps. It is stuck on Cloning repository.

It says Something went wrong! Application deployment to bluemix is taking longer than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this myself a few times and it always turned out to be some temporary issue in Bluemix or DevOps services for Bluemix. Unfortunately for now the only recommendation is to rerun the deployment again. If the problem continues through tomorrow then please let me know here.